# What is world space and eye space in game development?

Tags: opengl, 3d, game-engine

I am reading a book about 3D concepts and OpenGL. The book always talks about *world space*, *eye space*, and so on.

- What exactly is a *world* inside the computer monitor screen?
- What is the world space?
- What is eye space? Is it synonymous to projection?

Comment: world space is the world matrix ..i.e whole game map or area...while the eye projection is the view point of the object(it can be any view) i.e w.r.t a person or anyother object use in the game

Comment: this question is more suited for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BROY This [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) might help a bit

Comment: @BROY There's also this answer I wrote on a similar question that includes an example if that helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16226282/1122135

Comment: gamedev's duplicate question: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/65783/what-is-world-space-and-eye-space-in-game-development

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### World space

*World space* is the (arbitrarily chosen) frame of reference in which everything within the world is located in *absolute* coordinates.

---

### Local space

*Local space* is space relative to another local frame of reference, in coordinates *relative* to the local frame.

For example, the mesh of a model will be constructed in relation to a coordinate system local to the model. When you move around the model in the world, the relative positions to each other of the points making up the model don't change. But they change within the world.

Hence there exists a ***model-to-world* transformation** from local to world space.

---

### Eye (or view) space

Eye (or view) space is the world as seen by the viewer, i.e. all the positions of things in the world are no longer in relation to the (arbitrary) world coordinate system, but in relation to the viewer.

View space is somewhat special, because it ***not** arbitrarily chosen*. The coordinate `(0, 0, 0)` in view space is the position of the viewer and a certain direction (usually parallel to `Z`) is the direction of viewing.

So there exists a **transformation *world-to-view***. Now because the viewer is always at the origin of the view space, setting the viewpoint is done by defining the *world-to-view* transformation.

---

Since for the purposes of rendering the graphics world space is of little use, you normally coalesce *model-to-world* and *world-to-view* transformations into a single ***model-to-view* transformation**.

Note that eye (or view) space is ***not** the projection*. Projection happens by a separate projection transform that transforms ***view-to-clip* space**.

Answer (score 3):

You should read this: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/

That tutorial uses term "camera space" instead of "eye space" but they are the same.